# If light propagates as spherical waves, how do the photons from a laser go in a straight line?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

I know light travels in straight lines so that the momentum is conserved ($p=h/\lambda$).

However in some derivations I also see that electromagnetic waves propagate as spherical waves, like an expanding balloon.

I'm a bit confused by these two contradicting explanations. I'm not that good at physics. Has this something to do with wave-particle duality ? If so, should we assume **one photon** as **one expanding balloon** ? Appreciate any help in clearing this up for me. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate ??http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/how-is-a-spherical-electromagnetic-wave-emitted-from-an-antenna-described-in-ter?rq=1

Comment: That link seems to explain it nicely. Thank you (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of the boundary conditions. A [spherical light wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Spherical_waves) comes from a point hole, or a point source. The light waves of the sun , since a very small angle is subtended, can be considered a [plane wave.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave)

The light from a [laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_light) comes from a particular construction of crystals and reflective surfaces so that the light is coherent as a plane wave and has very small dispersion.

Comment: Ahh they are making the dispersion small by using special materials. Thank  you, that link is helpful (:  I'm still going through it. Is it correct to think that the source of any light is an atom( change in elctron state) ?  I guess we can assume the atoms are like point sources (1 Angstrom)...

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you imagine a lot of photons propagating in all directions. Each photon propagating in a straight line.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering what happens if my laser shoots only one photon. Would it propagate as an expanding sphere or take a straight path...